# Make the zoom slider of Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 and 7000 scroll up and down, in 14.04 (Trusty)

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, udev

I tried to use [this tutorial](http://shkspr.mobi/blog/2011/12/changing-the-microsoft-4000s-zoom-keys-in-ubuntu/) to make scroll switch work on my Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000. But I face following error:

```
sudo: /lib/udev/keymap: command not found
```

I have udev version `204-5ubuntu20.2` (the version found in Trusty)

I noticed that this version doesn't include `keymap` tool. But I notices that greater `udev` versions ([which available for Debian, for example](http://pkgs.org/debian-sid/debian-main-amd64/udev_204-10_amd64.deb.html)) include this tool.

Could somebody explain this diff for me? =) And what should I do in this case - install package from Debian repo?

Comment: Do you want to resolve this issue using udev or are you fine with alternatives? I would be a bit reluctant to install unpackaged udev debian packages on ubuntu.

Comment: any alternatives are welcome =)

Comment: Does [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2182054&p=12821913#post12821913) help?

Comment: What does the no longer shipped `keymap` utility do anyway?

Comment: I've updated my tutorial (that you linked to) to include the below answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000's zoom slider (and other buttons) to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33038/how-to-get-microsoft-natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000s-zoom-slider-and-other-bu) (both questions give valid but similar answers)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you look at `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-keyboard.rules` you'll see that everything has been messed around with. This is just part of the udev merger into systemd that has gone on.

All hardware rules are compiled into a binary hardware database. These follow a really strange format. The existing rules for keyboards that ship with udev live in `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb`. Look at that but **don't edit it** (updates will probably overwrite it).

To add your custom rules, we'll create a new file in `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/` by running `sudoedit /etc/udev/hwdb.d/61-keyboard-local.hwdb`. All you need to do is paste in the following -

If you are using the 4000 model:

```
keyboard:usb:v045Ep00DB*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_0c022d=pageup
 KEYBOARD_KEY_0c022e=pagedown
```

If you are using 7000 model:

```
keyboard:usb:v045Ep071D*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_0c022d=pageup
 KEYBOARD_KEY_0c022e=pagedown
```

This is adapated from the tutorial you posted so you might need to tweak based on your keyboard. Look at `lsusb` and make sure the `vendor:product` code above (as `v####p####`) is correct. It won't work if they don't match.

Once you're done editing, recompile the `hwdb` that udev uses:

```
sudo udevadm hwdb --update
```

And then you *might* need to re-plug. If it's a PS/2 keyboard you might need to reboot. In some cases you also need to reboot.

Comment: Thx for reply! `hwdb.d` dir is empty, `rules.d` contains only 3 files(`70-persistent-cd.rules`, `70-persistent-net.rules`, `README`). So, did you mean that I must create a new file? Or I must have some to edit?

Comment: Yeah you should be creating a new file. The existing keyboard rules are sitting in `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb` but edits to it will be lost after udev updates.

Comment: unfortunately, doesn't make target button to work

Comment: device id was checked with `lsusb` as you mentioned

Comment: Hmm, looking at things again, the v:p codes might need to be caps. Try `keyboard:usb:v045Ep00DB*`

Comment: hmmm.. doesn't work for me too, even when changing lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb itself.
Interestingly, the zoom scroll doesn't zoom either, even though it _is_ picked up by `evtest` (at least in Chrome and Firefox).

Comment: Now it works! (Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 7000, not 4000). Must have required that reboot after `sudo udevadm hwdb --update` even though the 7000 is not a PS/2 keyboard.

Maybe `udevadm trigger` is necessary after the `update` but haven't tried that and you should read about that command before trying it, for myself I haven't used it before.

Comment: I tried everything on my 4000! I updated the hardware database and put the letters in all caps and everything! I noticed that before KEYBOARD_KEY (both times) there is a space. Would it help if I replaced that with a tab instead?

Comment: BTW, any way of making it work for both keyboard models, with the same configuration?

Comment: @matt, you can put multiple aliases as [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11813942/)

Comment: Oh great, good to know!!

Comment: On Debian Jessie 8.5 this didn't work. Answer below by @user261903 is the right choice in this case.

Comment: Instead of plugging|unpluging one can use `udevadm trigger /dev/input/by-id/usb-Microsoft-*` to trigger the update

Comment: I found the scrolling using _pageup_ and _pagedown_ key bindings to be too fast. Instead on can use _up_ and _down_ for a slower scrolling.

Answer (score 38):

**Ubuntu 15.10**: I had no success with previous answers.

I have successfully used approach similar to the previous ones - instructions were mentioned in `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb`.

I've created new hwdb file using `sudo nano /etc/udev/hwdb.d/70-keyboard.hwdb`
containing:

```
# Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 - remap zoom in/out to page up/down
evdev:input:b0003v045Ep00DB*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c022d=pageup
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c022e=pagedown
```

after that I've run

```
sudo udevadm hwdb --update
sudo udevadm control --reload
```

and replugged the keyboard and it worked.

For model 7000 use 
`evdev:input:b003v045Ep071D*`

Comment: This is correct answer for Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Thanks. It indeed looks like the `keyboard:` definitions no longer work on Ubuntu 1604 and it needs to be `evdev:`. There is even a default mapping in `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb` for the 4000 model that maps them to `zoomin`/`zoomout` - however X completely ignores the events (xev shows nothing) so you still need a configuration change like this.

Comment: The `b0003` looks like it's bus-specific (so it might only work in some USB ports). If something like  `b*v045Ep071D*` works, that might be better.

Comment: Thanks, it's working in Ubuntu 16.04 (`evdev:input:XXX` instead of `keyboard:usb:YYY`). You can also use different mapping instead of `pageup`/`pagedown`. For example, I am using `scrollup` and `scrolldown` to do real scrolling.

Comment: Thank you guys. Finally convinced my ancient  Microsoft Corp. Digital Media Keyboard 1.0A to switch songs in Spotify.
https://gist.github.com/mauron85/5f4b640aa4e5e968e0496ac5a0878715

Comment: Works in Kubuntu 17.10 as well

Answer (score 7):

The original solution posted by Oli did not work for me, but it works after I changed the key numbers `"0c022d"` and `"0c022e"` to `"c022d"` and `"c022e"`. I'm using a 4000 model, so I can't verify if the same change is needed for the 7000 model.

To repeat Oli's answer, here is what I did: create a new file by running `sudo nano /etc/udev/hwdb.d/61-keyboard-local.hwdb`. Paste the following lines to the file (for the 4000 model):

```
keyboard:usb:v045Ep00DB*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c022d=pageup
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c022e=pagedown
```

After editing the file, recompile the hwdb that udev uses:

```
sudo udevadm hwdb --update
```

Then replug the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks. Oddly enough I needed to perform this change too now, and also a restart was required after it all (not just replugging).

Comment: worked for me on Ubuntu 15.04. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me on Debian Jessie 8.5.

Comment: I want to buy an economic keyboard, and I am curious, whether it works with 16.04 LTS? Or there is not a problem like this there.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Oli's answer,
If you want line scrolling like how it is on a mouse, you can modify pageup/pagedown to up/down in your custom rule. Like:

```
keyboard:usb:v045Ep00DB*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c022d=up
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c022e=down
```

Comment: By the way: Up/Down is default in 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

Nice solution is [here](https://www.logilab.org/blogentry/68294), and I can only add that you can map the keys to unused X keys like that:

```
$ cat /lib/udev/rules.d/95-keymap.rules
...
ENV{ID_VENDOR}=="Microsoft", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="00db", RUN+="keymap $name 0xc022d katakana 0xc022e katakanahiragana
...
```

Proper names to use instead of `katakana` can be found [here](https://hal.freedesktop.org/quirk/quirk-keymap-list.txt).

After reboot ;-) you can test that `zoomin` and `zoomout` keys are mapped successfully, and also to find out a proper names of the keys (to use in `rc.xml` for OpenBox WM, for example) using `xev`:

```
$ xev
...
KeyRelease event, serial 46, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x291, subw 0x0, time 1492891, (-261,-61), root:(573,380),
    state 0x0, keycode 101 (keysym 0xff27, Hiragana_Katakana), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
...
```

Now you can connect new keys to completely arbitrary action. In my case of OpenBox window manager I used something like this:

```
$ cat <whatever>/rc.xml
...
<keybind key="Katakana">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>volume_up.sh</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="Hiragana_Katakana">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>volume_down.sh</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
...
```