# udev keyboard mapping, gnome 3 workspace

Tags: gnome, keyboard, udev, workspace-switcher

I’m using the [Microsoft 4000 keyboard](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-gb/p/natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000), and a managed to map the zoom keys to pageup and pagedown in udev using [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471802/make-the-zoom-slider-of-microsoft-natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000-and-7000-scrol). But I want to be able to map them to workspace up/down in gnome 3. could anybody tell me what commands would do that? Or how I could map it to multiple keys like shift+alt+ctrl+pageup? so I could assign that in the keyboard manager.

thanks

Comment: Workspace up/down is Super+PgUp/PgDn.

Comment: A scancode can only have one keycode, not more. Try this: 1. Remove the mapping. 2. Open `shortcuts` and change the keys for `Next Workspace` and `Previous Workspace` in the category `Navigation`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: yes I have changed the keys to ctrl+s and ctrl+x. and that worked fine

Comment: well you cannot map the zoom slider into the short cut by its self. for whatever reason. it just wont acknowledge it. so i guess if you cannot use udev to map more than one key then that’s not going to be an option. as there are no available single keys that i can use for that. what i need to know is weather there would be a specific command in udev that will move the workspace down.