# How to remap Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboard 2019 model the Office and the Emoji keys?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, microsoft-keyboard

Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboard the 2019 model (not the old one 4000 model) generates several keystrokes for the new keys. It is well known how to remap [the Zoom slider](https://askubuntu.com/q/471802/28004) of the old version however the question is how to do that for the new keys. The udev rules allow to specify only one scancode for a mapping entry, for example `KEYBOARD_KEY_0c022d=pageup`.

Here is an output of `evtest` for the Office key:

```
Event: time 1604142043.024827, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e0
Event: time 1604142043.024827, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 1
Event: time 1604142043.024827, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e1
Event: time 1604142043.024827, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 42 (KEY_LEFTSHIFT), value 1
Event: time 1604142043.024827, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e2
Event: time 1604142043.024827, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 56 (KEY_LEFTALT), value 1
Event: time 1604142043.024827, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e3
Event: time 1604142043.024827, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA), value 1
```

and here for the Emoji key:

```
Event: time 1604142174.537667, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e0
Event: time 1604142174.537667, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 1
Event: time 1604142174.537667, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e1
Event: time 1604142174.537667, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 42 (KEY_LEFTSHIFT), value 1
Event: time 1604142174.537667, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e2
Event: time 1604142174.537667, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 56 (KEY_LEFTALT), value 1
Event: time 1604142174.537667, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e3
Event: time 1604142174.537667, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA), value 1
Event: time 1604142174.537667, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1604142174.545449, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 7002c
Event: time 1604142174.545449, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 57 (KEY_SPACE), value 1
```

So the Office key generates only the modifiers keystrokes and the Emoji key generates the modifiers keystrokes and the space keystroke after about 8 milliseconds. There are also other new custom keys on that keyboard which generate servers keystrokes, however the Office and Emoji keys are most important to remap because of their location.

Comment: It's easier to press the Alt and Ctrl keys on a Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboard than on an ordinary keyboard. But I also want an Alt key on the right side. One of Office or Emoji keys would be good for that.

Comment: There already is an Alt key on the right side. It's in between the space bar and office key.