# Is there an Ubuntu version of the software for the Microsoft Ergonomic Natural 4000 kb?

Tags: 18.04, microsoft-keyboard

I am looking for an updated answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33038/how-to-get-microsoft-natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000s-zoom-slider-and-other-bu/817096#817096) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471802/make-the-zoom-slider-of-microsoft-natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000-and-7000-scrol).  After reading those two posts, I have no idea if any of the suggestions will apply to 18.04 because they're rather old.  Also, while those posts request help for only certain buttons, I need help for all of the special buttons except Volume (Favorites, Calculator, navigation).  The normal keys work (home, end, pgdn, pgup, number pad, etc.).

**Do I need to do this? -->**

> Create the file /etc/udev/rules.d/98-ms-ergo.rules with the following contents:
>
> ACTION=="remove", GOTO="keyboard_end"
>      KERNEL!="event*", GOTO="keyboard_end"
>      ENV{ID_INPUT_KEY}=="", GOTO="keyboard_end"
>      SUBSYSTEMS!="usb", GOTO="keyboard_end"
>
> SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", IMPORT{builtin}="usb_id"
>
> ENV{ID_VENDOR}=="Microsoft", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="00db", RUN+="keymap $name 0xc022d pageup 0xc022e pagedown"
>
> GOTO="keyboard_end"

Or is there something available in the repository?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this keyboard with XFCE on Ubuntu 18.04. The zoom slider works out of the box.

If you find that all function keys are not working on the Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 v1.0
check that the F-lock is toggled.  On the top row of the keyboard, next to the F12 key there's a button called `F lock`. Pressing it toggles a green LED at the bottom of the keyboard with an F below it.  When the LED is off, the function keys F1, F2 etc don't work.